# Lightswitch Computed property wont compile

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2012

I keep making computed propeties on my table, but when I go to edit the code (even using the "Edit Method" link), I can't compile because it says the defining declaration is mia.

Here's an error example.

```
Error 1  No defining declaration found for implementing declaration of partial method 'LightSwitchApplication.CampaignLevel.Property1_Compute(ref string)'
C:\Users\Jason\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Application1\Application1\Common\UserCode\CampaignLevel.cs
11 22  Common
```

Code behind is empty:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.LightSwitch;
namespace LightSwitchApplication
{
    public partial class CampaignLevel
    {

        partial void Property1_Compute(ref string result)
        {
            // Set result to the desired field value

        }
    }
}
```

I have 1 that works in the project on a different table, but I can't for the life of me figure out what the difference is and why that one works and any others I try to create don't.

Does anyone know what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I would try re-creating the property. The Property definition is created elsewhere (The application definitions), and is passed on to this user code file for you to reference. If there is no reference, then there may have been a problem saving the other files somehow.

More information may be needed to give a more definitive answer, but that's what I would try first.